# 12-hour format is used, though 24-hour format is specified

Tags: scala

I am saving some streaming data on S3. I use the format of year-month-day-hour-minutes in order to put the titles to folders.

The problem is that folders seem to be named in 12-hour format, though I am using `yyyyMMddHHmm`:

```
val sdf_sec = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
val foldername = sdf_sec.format(new Date(time.milliseconds))

rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("s3n://" + bucketNameData + "/" + stream_folder + "/" + foldername)
```

Comment: `sdf_sec.format(System.currentTimeMillis())` yields `201702281552`, which looks fine according to my watch.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Do you mean that I should use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `new Date(time.milliseconds)`?

Comment: I'm not even sure what `time` is. I just mean the formatting works fine.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `time` is obtained from `myDstream.window(Seconds(100), Seconds(100)).foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from the old Date/time classes to the new `java.time` classes. Use this:

```
scala> val fmt = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
scala> val df = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt)
scala> val foldername = java.time.LocalDateTime.now.format(df)
foldername: String = 201702281104
```